# Ursina not importing in python

Tags: python, importerror, ursina

I'm getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\blocky\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ursina as ue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ursina'
```

I tried:

`pip install ursina`

wait I also did

`python -m pip install ursina`

Comment: How do you run your Python program?

Comment: What happened when you tried to installed ursina via pip?

Comment: statisfied but still didnt import
 ,runed by idle

Comment: Idle probably runs from a different Python installation than on your shell. Check the settings and search around, this is a very common problem. You have to make sure to install the package for the right Python installation.

Comment: i tried........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using **import ursina as (custom name)**, you currently importing *ursina as a local namespace* and doing this will be annoying for most beginners.
Example: `(namespace).function()/PACKAGE CONTENT.function()`

I recommend that you use `from ursina import *` because this will extract everything and remove the need for namespace on every function/PACKAGE CONTENT.

Example: `function()/PACKAGE CONTENT.function()`

Also, try reinstalling python.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pipwin.
First do

```
pip install pipwin,
```

Then do `pipwin install ursina`

Comment: That doesn't work on linux neither mac

Answer (score 0):

You must have any other libraries installed in the same virtual
environment or the default, that causes conflict with 'ursina'

**Try store the libraries u use in the project in a new empty virtual environment**

---

> 1, Install https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/

```
 pip install virtualenv
```

> 2, Create a new folder for your environment (by convention it is advisable to call it venv.) locate the folder with the console

```
source /python -m virtualenv .
```

> 3, Active (to deactivate it would be the same but in the end it is placed deactivate.)

-- in Windows

```
 source /venv/Scripts/activate
```

-- in Linux

```
 source /venv/bin/activate
```

the name of the virtual environment will appear at the beginning of the line in the command terminal, (venv in this case).

> 4, To see the packages that we have installed in our virtual environment we execute the following command:

```
(venv) source  /pip list
```

> 5, install **'ursina'** n all the libs u need

```
(venv) source  /pip install ursina
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install ursina (neither one option from above worked), just download the GitHub repository and import ursina from there. You will need to put the folder inside your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following proper command:

```
python3.10 pip -m install ursina
```

Fix at the documentation ursina requires python 3.10 or latest to work.

What induces that issues is what when we install any package in Python it self try to fix the broken dependencies by us, in that case that make the ursina installation pends on the python3 installation and not even python3.10 which is required.

Comment: Dear OP, please see [answer]. There are still grammatical mistakes in the answer, I'd request you to correct it.

Answer (score -1):

use this instead

```
from ursina import *

app= Ursina()
(code)
app.run()
```

this will help your issue

Comment: Writing the import in a different way won't help if the import itself fails.